# I'm trying to create a yes or no dialogue tree

Tags: python

This is my first time posting so I apologize if it is a disaster. I'm Trying to teach myself code and would like to create a yes or no dialogue tree. It should prompt the user to answer the question and if the answer is not yes or no it should reprint the question to use. if the answer is yes it should print a yes1 response and end the sequence. If the input is no it should proceed to the next question. and continue until a yes1[3] or no1[4] response is printed ending the entire sequence.
instead it continues no mater what response you input or if you hit Enter. it continues to the next question until it reaches the last question. Then it begins to print all the yes1 and no1 replies. once all are printed it then goes on an infinite loop of your last input.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
    #have tried with and without this yes or no bool
yes = True

yes == True

no = False

no == False

#str

#str prints the question but negates user input

#continues to next question if Enter is press

#as well as any other input.

#0
quest0 = ('Could I please have a cookie? \n')
can = (input(quest0))

#1
quest1 = ("please?\n")
i = (input(quest1))

#2
quest2 = ('just one?\n')
please = (input(quest2))

#3
quest3 = ("what if i never ask for another cookie again?\n" +
          ".......until tomorrow.\n")
have = (input(quest3))



#list y/n
#replies print after all questions are asked and do not follow sequence
#have tried with and without the input
#if replies are yes
yes1 = [
    #0
    (input("sure, here you go.")),
    #1
    (input("ok but just half.")),
    #2
    (input("ok sure, but after dinner.")),
    #3
    (input("sure, might have one too.")),
    #4
    (input("why not, it's been a day")),
]
#if replies are no
#have tried this with and without the input
no1 = [
    #0
    ("Not today honey",
     #1
     (input("no, you'll spoil your dinner.")),
     #2
     (input("you had 2 yesterday, not today hun")),
     #3
     (input("we're all out, we'll get some at the store later")),
     ]

    #initial quest 0
    #should take initial input to start seuqence
    #it does print
    print(str(can))

    #y/n loop for can: instead it moves on to next like regardless of input
    while (str(can)) != (yes or no):
    print(str(can))
    #once yes or no complied move on
    while (str(can)) == (yes or no):
        print(str(can))
    continue


    #prints yes1 #0
    if (str(can)) == yes:
        print(yes1[0])
        break
        #should end quest 0 sequence

    #1  should take user no input and print quest 1
    elif (str(can)) == no:
        print(str(can))
        while (str(can)) == no:
            print(str(i))
        continue
        #continues to quest 1

    #1        #quest 1 y/n loop
        while (str(i)) != (yes or no):
            print(str(i))
            #when yes or no complied begin next sequence
            while (str(i)) == (yes or no):
                print(str(i))
            continue
            #continues with quest 1

            #should print yes1 #1 and end sequence
            if (str(i)) == yes:
                print(yes1[1])
                break
                #sequence should end here

            #if no print quest 2
            elif (str(i)) == no:
                print(str(please))
            continue
            #continues to quest 2

            #quest 2 y/n loop
            while (str(please)) != (yes or no):
                print(str(please))
                #when yes or no complied begin next sequence
            while(str(please)) == (yes or no):
                print(str(please))
                continue
    #continue to next sequence

    #1              #should print yes1 #2
                if (str(please)) == yes:
                    print(yes1[2])
                    break
                    #sequence ends here


                #should print quest 3
                elif (str(please)) == no:
                    print(str(have))
                continue

                    #quest 3 y/n loop
                while (str(have)) != (yes or no):
                    print(str(have))
                    #if yes or no complied move on
                    while (str(have)) == (yes or no):
                        print(str(have))
                    continue
                    #should continue

                    # prints yes1 #3
                    if (str(have)) == yes:
                        print(yes1[3])
                        break
                        #sequence should end here

                    #should print no1 #4
                    elif (str(have)) == no:
                        print(no1[4])
                    break
                    #entire sequence should  end here
                    #doesnt end here instead it 
                     continues to
                     print all yes1 and no1 str if i
                     continue to hit Enter and then goes 
                     off
                     in an infinite loop repeating last
                     input
```

Comment: You're needlessly overusing parens i.e. (input("sure, here you go.")), (str(i)), (str(please)), etc.  Simplify to: input("sure, here you go."), str(i), str(please), etc.

Comment: I'm confused by your placement of continue statements.  Either your indents are wrong or you have lots of "dead code".

Comment: @DarrylG I thought you used continue once you want it to go to the next line after the conditions have been met. Am i mistaken?

Comment: @DarrylG thank you I'll implement that now. really i got desperate and tried to see if i was using it wrong. Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: @DiarrheaisGodsModernWrath--yes, continue is used differently.  When used in a control block, such as `for or while`, it restarts with the next iteration of the block, skipping the code from the point below it.  [Break and Continue](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm#:~:text=The%20continue%20statement%20in%20Python,both%20while%20and%20for%20loops.)

Comment: @DiarrheaisGodsModernWrath--I was looking at redoing your code but was a bit confused about what it was trying to do.  I would suggest starting with a single question and answer to better understand the pattern of prompting for an input, and repeating the question until the desired response.

Comment: @DarrylG understood, thank you for clearing that up. I was trying to create a dialogue between a parent and child for a cookie. Then i realized what i had set up didn't work so I held off on inserting the other no1 answers until I figured out what i was doing wrong. I appreciate you trying to redo my code, didn't expect that. I apologize for the sloppy mess I started about 2 weeks ago.

Comment: @DiarrheaisGodsModernWrath--glad to help since it helps with my own code writing.  I'll take another look at your code.

Comment: @DiarrheaisGodsModernWrath--how close does [this code](https://repl.it/join/kzphqloh-darrylgurganiou) come to doing what you want?  You can run it by hitting the green "run" button at the top middle.

Comment: @DarrylG that's exactly what i was going for. Dam I wasn't even close lol. Thanks for your help, I appreciate your time. hope you don't mind if I go ahead and study this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

```
yes = "yes"
no = 'no'

questions = ['Could I please have a cookie?',
             'please?',
             'just one?',
             'what if i never ask for another cookie again?\n.......until tomorrow']

yeses = ["sure, here you go.",
          "ok but just half.",
          "ok sure, but after dinner.",
          "sure, might have one too.",
          "why not, it's been a day"]

nos = ['no way',
      "not today honey",
      "no, you'll spoil your dinner.",
      "you had 2 yesterday, not today hun",
      "we're all out, we'll get some at the store later"
     ]

for i, question in enumerate(questions):
  while True:
    # loop until they respond with yes or no
    answer = input(question).lower()
    if answer != yes and answer != no:
      print('answer yes or no please')
      continue  # continue while loop since wasn't yes/no
    break       # discontinue while loopo

  if answer == yes:
    print(yeses[i])  # output i-th yes response
    break
  else:
    print(nos[i])    # output i-th no response
else:
  print("Sorry, you don't get a cookie")
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, change every occurrence of this:

```
x != (yes or no)
```

To this:

```
x != yes and x != no
```

Or to this:

```
x not in [yes, no]
```